# gulp-insert exclude wrap certain files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-insert

I want to use gulp-insert to do wrapping on every JS file, except `.module.js` file.

Here is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('compressjs', function() {
    gulp.src("local/app/**/*.js")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    // wrap each individual JS file
    .pipe(insert.wrap('(function(){"use strict";', '\n})();'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app'));
}
```

It is wrapping every single JS file as expected. So, how can I exclude it from wrapping file with `.module.js` extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `gulp-add-src` by excluding the `.module.js` from the first source then piping it through `gulp-insert` and then adding the `.module.js`back to the source.

```
var addsrc = require("gulp-add-src");

gulp.task('compressjs', function() {
    gulp.src(["local/app/**/*.js", "!local/app/**/*.module.js"])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    // wrap each individual JS file
    .pipe(insert.wrap('(function(){"use strict";', '\n})();'))
    // add the modules file
    .pipe(addsrc("local/app/**/*.module.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app'));
}
```